# Sheets form a neighborhood basis of the covering space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, covering-spaces

I'm trying to understand the proof of Proposition 1.33 ([Hatcher, Algebraic topology, online](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)). The author proves that $\tilde{f}$ is continous at $y$, by showing that the preimage of a generic sheet containing $\tilde{f}(y)$ is open. This procedure implicitly assumes (as said  in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135031/proposition-1-33-in-hatchers-book)) that all of the possible sheets containing $\tilde{f}(y)$ form a neighborhood basis at $\tilde{f}(y)$. How can I prove this?
I tried showing that given a point $\tilde{x}$ in the total space of a covering map $p:\tilde{X}\to X$  and an open subset $V\subseteq \tilde{X}$, then $\tilde{U}\cap V$ is a sheet of $p(V\cap \tilde{U})$, where $\tilde{U}$ is a sheet containing $\tilde{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not true. But in Proposition 1.33 Hatcher considers covering maps with a locally path connected base space. This changes the game. In fact, $\tilde f(y)$ has a neighborhood base consisting of sheets as desired in your question. See [Preimages of evenly covered basis gives a basis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823903/preimages-of-evenly-covered-basis-gives-a-basis/3834914#3834914)

Comment: Thank you. Since I need this proof in my thesis, could you provide me a reference?

Comment: @FrancescoScavella Unfortunately not, I do not know any explicit reference in the literature. Perhaps you should state without proof some "folklore results". Or refer to this forum.